# Is there a way to have a React container respond to a Redux action?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the following container, and the issue is that when you remove a user from the organization, it doesn't reflect in the component `OrgUserManager`. Obviously I need to just make `orgMembers` change so that the prop passed into `OrgUserManager` changes, causing a re-render. But I'm not sure how to do that in response to a Redux action.

```
export default class OrgUserManagerContainer extends Component {
  addUser(userId) {
    this.props.dispatch(adminRequestAddUserToOrg(this.props.org._id, userId));
  }

  removeUserFromOrg(event) {
    this.props.dispatch(
      adminRequestRemoveUserFromOrg(this.props.org._id, event.target.id)
    );
  }

  render() {
    const orgMembers = this.props.org.getMembers();

    return <OrgUserManager
      org={this.props.org}
      users={this.props.users}
      orgMembers={orgMembers}
      onAddUser={this.addUser.bind(this)}
      onRemoveUserFromOrg={this.removeUserFromOrg.bind(this)}
    />
  }
}
```

Once the `ADMIN_ADD_USER_TO_ORG_SUCCEEDED` action fires off, I'd like this component to recognize that and cause a refresh. But I don't necessarily want to store the list of members in the Redux state, and I don't want to use the state as a hack to pass a success message. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The action must trigger a change in the redux state. And the change in the redux state must be made apparent - i.e. as one of the `props` - to the `OrgUserManagerContainer` component. Satisfy those two conditions, and your component will re-render. Put it another way: components don't respond to actions, they respond to state changes.